# New equiavalent to D3DXCOLOR Structure in Directx 11.1?

Tags: windows, sdk, directx

I am having trouble finding the `D3DXCOLOR` struct, it seems it is no longer there in DirectX 11.1 (`d3d11_1.h`).
I have searched for an equal of it but to no luck. Can someone help me with it? Also could you tell me how to use it if it has changed a lot?

Answer (score 10):

I'm a total noob to this and i too had the problem with a sample tutorial where they used it.
So after many hours searching the net.
drumroll
Tada....

Here is how I've converted it in my code

old code

```
// clear the back buffer to a deep blue
 devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR{ 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
```

new code

```
// clear the back buffer to a deep blue
float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, color);
```

Answer (score 10):

Use XMCOLOR. It is located in DirectXPackedVector.h

Answer (score 2):

How about declaring once

```
using RGBA = float[4]; //c++11
```

or

```
typedef float RGBA[4]; //pre-c++11
```

and then using wherever needed like this

```
devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, RGBA{0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f});
```

Answer (score 0):

D3DX or the DirectX Utility library has been removed, instead Microsoft wants you to use the XNA Math Library counterparts (that use SSEs & stuff, but in my case it kind of crashes sometimes so I stopped using it)